# How to consume a list of futures as soon as one completes in Scala

Tags: scala, future

I have a bunch of Futures that can complete at extremely different times, something like this:

```
val results = task.getAssignedFiles map {
  file: File => Future[Result] {
    <heavy computation>
  }
}
```

Now I want to iterate over `results` as soon as one of the input futures completes, basically poll all the futures in results until one completes, do some processing, and continue until all of them are done. Something like:

```
while (!results.allCompleted) {
  one = results.firstCompletedFuture
  process(one)
}
```

Comment: Better to have a look at ReactiveStreams impl such as Akka Streams

Comment: Are you saying I should convert my Futures as input to an Akka stream? I don't have too much experience with this, so any pointers would be useful

Comment: What happens to each future that completes?

Comment: @maasg I'll have something like future.onComplete { 
success => {}
failure => {}
}

Comment: There's no need to poll for results in that way. Chaining computations on the futures should get you the expected result. I've answered in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [firstCompletedOf](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#firstCompletedOf[T](futures:TraversableOnce[scala.concurrent.Future[T]])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]).

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, OP wants to process each result from the future computation, not only the first one. Maybe @UtsavShah can clarify.

Comment: You can do that later, by composing the sequenced list of the result from the `firstCompleteOf`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to "loop" over the list of Futures to take action on them when they complete. The approach is to chain 
the needed sequence of computations using combinators and wait until they all terminate.

In terms of the code above that could be written as:

```
val results:List[Future[Result] = task.getAssignedFiles map {
  file: File => Future[Result] {
    <heavy computation>
  }
} 
val processedResults:List[Future[ProcessedResult]] = results.map(result => process(result))
val finalResults:Future[List[ProcessedResult]] = Future.sequence(processedResults)
```

Note that all futures are running from the moment they are defined. `sequence` will finalize at the moment the last of them is done.

Comment: Once one of the future is done, I want to make sure that the remaining work is done by the same thread, since the dependent work is going to write to one big file. But it doesn't matter what order these futures will complete. So I don't want to chain it like this.

Comment: @UtsavShah The writing can be done in the context of the future, using  proper locking. The net result will be the same while the logic will be much easier to write.